# When a BLE devices is discoverable?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, contact-tracing-api

I'm trying to write an app that will be able to see when a lot of people are close inside a single area. I was thinking to use BLE. I don't have a good knowledge of this technology and I have a single, but big question. In modern days, how easy is it to see a BL device that is actually transmitting and discoverable in places like streets, etc...? It's my idea very dumb? Will my idea work with the spread of contact-tracing apps?? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can scan the Bluetooth frequency bands to detect devices that are advertising themselves, so yes, this is possible.

What might be more difficult is making sense of it all. If I run a Bluetooth scanner in my study, I get dozens of devices, most of which I have no idea what they are. A lot of them will probably belong to the people living next door; some advertise their name (Apple TV, for example), but most don't. If you look at the signal strength you can probably rule out a fair few devices that are too far away for your purposes.